# How to sum PatientName with number of hours within 7 day span (if they have over 9)

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have to find PatientName when they have 9 hours or more within a 7 days span. Then provide sum of hours by PatientName. Example:

TempTable1 pulls one year of data:

```
PatientName       VisitDate       Hours
Steve             11/2/2016        1
Steve             11/3/2016        1
Pete              11/1/2016        3
Pete              11/2/2016        7
Dave              11/1/2016        3
Dave              11/2/2016        3
Dave              2/2/2016         3
```

Steve doesn't have enough hours.  Dave has 9 hours but are not within 7 days.  Pete has 10 hours within 7 days. Therefore output should be like:

```
   PatientName          (SUM)Hours
   Pete                    10
```

This is simply beyond my ability.  I think this will take a multi select with lead and lag, but this is simply beyond my ability level

Hopefully some SQL ninja god can do this.  Please save me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method is a self-join with aggregation:

```
select t1.patientname, sum(t2.hours)
from temptable1 t1 join
     temptable1 t2
     on t2.patientname = t1.patientname and
        t2.visitdate >= t1.visitdate and
        t2.visitdate < datead(day, 7, t1.visitdate)
group by t1.patientname
having sum(t2.hours) >= 9;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I am also working on trying this one...it doesn't appear to work quite right.  I think it is not differentiating those where visits all happened within 7 days, just where total is > 9.  Also for the (hourS) in select and sum, should those be t1.sum or t2. sum?  I'm amazed at this approach

Comment: I wasn't able to completely use this as it was written, but did get a slight variation of this to work.  Can't thank you enough for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Following query helps you get the desired output:

```
select patient_name,week,sum(hours) as hours_served from
(
select patient_name,date,hours,week(date) as week
from temptable1
)
group by patient_name,week
having hours_served >=9;
```

Comment: Greetings- This is wonderful and elegant.  Trying to implement now.  I am using SSMS 2012 and got the msg 'week' is not a recognized built-in function name.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp
(
    PatientName VARCHAR(32),
    VisitDate   DATE,
    [Hours]     INT
)

INSERT #Temp
VALUES

('Steve', CAST('11/2/2016' AS DATE), 1),
('Steve', CAST('11/3/2016' AS DATE), 1),
('Pete', CAST('11/1/2016' AS DATE), 3),
('Pete', CAST('11/2/2016' AS DATE), 7),
('Dave', CAST('11/1/2016' AS DATE), 3),
('Dave', CAST('11/2/2016' AS DATE), 3),
('Dave', CAST('2/2/2016' AS DATE), 3)

SELECT p.PatientName, MAX(p.HoursSum)
FROM (
    SELECT t2.PatientName, SUM(t2.[Hours]) AS HoursSum
    FROM #Temp t1
        JOIN #Temp t2 ON t1.PatientName = t2.PatientName AND t2.VisitDate BETWEEN t1.VisitDate AND DATEADD(DAY, 7, t1.VisitDate)
    GROUP BY t2.PatientName, t1.VisitDate
    HAVING SUM(t2.[Hours]) >= 9
) p
GROUP BY p.PatientName

DROP TABLE #Temp
```